# Is ius's epel the same repository as fedoralprojects?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, repository

Are the following the same repository?  Thanks

- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL
- http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/repoview/epel-release.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the epel-release-6-5.noarch rpm will add the EPEL repo with this baseurl:

```
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
```

Comment: Thanks, had me confused.  Will either pgp key work?

Comment: It is the exact same key, in fact IUS is just mirroring that package from Fedora.